# Swift Storyboard error: Unable to backwards deploy Storyboard References for Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

We are currently trying to build a Swift ios app, getting a weird error.

> / com.apple.ibtool.warnings / : warning: Unable to validate Storyboard
>   References for Main1.storyboard. : warning: Unable to validate
>   Storyboard References for Main1.storyboard. / com.apple.ibtool.errors
>   / : error: Unable to backwards deploy Storyboard References for
>   Main1.storyboard.

what does backwards deploy mean?

Comment: what is your storyboardname ?

Comment: have you solved it ?

Comment: Hi Badal, sorry I forgot about the question completely, thanks for the answer, It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Firstly try to change your storyboard name with **Main.storyboard**

if it fails then,

2) Right click - > Delete file -> Click on remove reference .

[image]

[image]

then Add it again with ,

[image]

[image]

//Your Storyboard name will be **Main1.storyboard**

And lastly, check your storyboardname in this 2 places,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you may create storyboard use code, it will show warning. don't care about it.

```
storyBoardName = @"MajorTest";
storyBoardName = @"SecondTest";
storyBoardName = @"UIDesign";


self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyBoardName bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```